My question highlighted a typo in my reference book, what should I do?
My question here
A tricky integral inequality in analytical mechanics proof
has just been replied.
The answer revealed that the reason why I could not find a solution myself (sufficient but not necessary :)) was that the formula I took from my reference book had a typo.
What is now the best way to cope with this and be useful to the community?
Should I re-edit the question indicating the reference book and the correct formula?
I don't think I can delete my question now (it has an accepted answer) and it would probably be useful to other that find the same formula. Though probably now it would be more useful in physics.stackexchange.com now that the math has been sorted out.
Any suggestion?
thanks

I would just make sure that the details of where you found the (incorrect) formula are in your question as that will make the question and answer easier to find for anyone who is searching who has the same problem (namely that the book has a typo).  The answer provides the correction of the formula so putting it in the question might be seen as a little rude.

@postmortes thanks I have added an update on the top of my question where I also added the details of the book

Generally questions based on typos are not useful to other users so they should be deleted (else they exacerbate one of the biggest problems of the site - that it is difficult if not impossible to search for answers due to many unhelpful search results).
